# Trying to use discord.py to make the bot send a message as the command originator

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to create a bot on discord to tag things with tone indicators (i.e., /s for sarcasm) This project started off as just a library but then I realized I could have it append the tone indicator to the end of the message by using it as an argument. However, I can only get the bot to send it as itself, which is disappointing because it interrupts the flow of conversations. I'm writing it using python. Here's my code:

```py
import discord
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext # Importing the newly installed library.

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True) # Declares slash commands through the client.

guild_ids = [guild id] # Put your server ID in this array.

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")


@slash.slash(name="j", description="joking", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def j(ctx:SlashContext, message:str): # Defines a new "context" (ctx) command called "ping."
    await ctx.respond(eat=True)
    send_message = await ctx.send(f"{message} /j")
    def check(message):
        return message.author.id == ctx.author_id
    try:
        answer = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout = 60.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You took to long to answer...", hidden=True)
    else:
        # do something with answer (convert to tone indicator)
        pass

client.run("bot token")
```

I know I don't actually need any of the last part, but it was suggested to me as a work around to make it ID the user. It returns nothing. Anyone know how to make it send as the user who inputted the command, or mask itself as such?

Answer (score 1):

You can use webhooks for this

```py
#inside your command
guild = client.get_channel(ctx.channel_id)
if channel is None:
    #error here
    return
webhooks = filter(lambda x: x.user == client.user, await channel.webhooks()) #gets only webhooks created by us
if len(webhooks) == 0:
   webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name='something')
else: webhook = webhooks[0]

await webhook.send(content, username=ctx.author.username, avatar = ctx.author.avatar_url
```

### References:

- [Webhooks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhooks#discord.Webhook)
- [getting webhooks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhooks#discord.TextChannel.webhooks)
- [sending messages with webhooks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhooks#discord.TextChannel.webhooks)
- [discord-slash get channel id](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_109.html#objects-of-the-command-invoke)

Comment: So I tried to implement this solution right after the line `await ctx.respond(eat=True)`, but found it just ate the message and then nothing happened. I think this is some kind of linkage issue, so I tried changing `await webhook.send(content, username=ctx.author.username, avatar = ctx.author.avatar_url)` to `await webhook.send(f"{meesage} /j", username=ctx.author.username, avatar = ctx.author.avatar_url)`. The bot seems to be just eating the message and the not giving me any output. I know python is picky about order, so is there something wrong with my placement or is it some other problem?

Comment: My fault, confused `discord_slash`'s ctx and `discord.py`'s ctx. Updated answer now